# determine if two traces are overlap with each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I got two traces like [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6KFp.png).

I want to find at which interval they overlapped.
For this plot, the overlap interval is at [5.2,6.8].
My solution is:

- for every two connected points on the blue trace (get the linear function, call it line 1)
- I'll search for, is there any point from the orange trace fall in this range.
- If I found one, then this point and the point before this point, will form a line (get the linear function, call it line 2).
- find the intersection of line 1 and line 2.
- if the intersection is within the smallest range from line 1 and line 2, they intersect.
- if not do the same process with the line created by this point and the point after it.
- Finally, loop through all the points on the blue trace.

I'm wondering is there any other efficient way to solve this problem? 
I guess python and matlab probably have build-in functions to achieve this, but I'm writing this in JavaScript, so any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't sound too bad. I would give it a shot.

Comment: at first java!===javascript

Comment: the picture wasn't right, I'll try to fix it

Comment: @MaXon Try it, see if there are errors and come back with the code

Comment: what do you mean by overlap?? a change of f1(x)<f2(x) ?

Comment: @Jonasw I want to find the intersect interval. Have a look the picture

Comment: @MaXon so if ive got you you simply want the intersections then group two of them?

Comment: @Jonasw yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply get near to the intersection like this:

```
//given two functions ( in a math way) f1,f2
var compared=f1(0)<f2(0);
var intersections=[];
for(range=0;range<1000;range+=0.001){
  if(compared!==(f1(range)<f2(range))){
     intersections.push(range);
     compared!=compared;
  }
}
```

This approach works for all kind of functions, but if weve got a set of linear functions we can get crossing points by doing some simple math:

```
f1(x) = a1 * x + b1;
f2(x) = a2 * x + b2;
f1(x)=f2(x)
a1 * x + b1 = a2 * x + b2 | -b1 -(a2*x)
a1 * x - a2 * x = b2 - b1 | :(a1-a2)
x= (b2-b1)/(a1-a2);
```

Comment: what do the f1 and f2 represent? the linear function generated by two points?

Comment: @MaXon yes? if its really linear we can do basic math... ( yours isnt linear)

Comment: I understand the bottom part, that's find the intersection point

Comment: I'll write my solution to code and see how it goes. Thanks for your help